# No sound or networking

Tags: wireless, drivers

So yesterday I broke my sudo when I changed the permissions of the /usr folder. But late into the night I was able to restore it.

Now my sound and networking do not work. Videos also do not play because the sound doesn't work. It also doesn't show me the battery meter. `apt-get -f install`, `dpkg --configure -a`, and, `sudo apt-get update` && `sudo apt-get install upgrade` don't help, the last one because there isn't any internet connection.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you restore the permissions of the /usr folder back to how they should be? The reason I ask is because you may have to change the permissions on many other sub folders as well.

Comment: I entered recovery mode, then went into root shell. Then I did chown root:root /usr and chmod u+s /usr. Do I need to change permission of all subfolders? Is the what is causing this?

Comment: I would think so, see the answer below by @Lion

Answer (score 0):

is a jungle there....

all in the /usr is under the root user so i guess that a

chown root:root usr
chown root:root usr/*
chown root:root usr/*/*
chown root:root usr/*/*/*

should do the trick....

the problem is that

root@ubuntu:/usr/include# ll sound/
total 144
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  6 01:27 ./
drwxr-xr-x 53 root root 20480 Jul  6 01:27 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 22029 Jun 18 21:35 asequencer.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4313 Jun 18 21:35 asound_fm.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 39635 Jun 18 21:35 asound.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 16843 Jun 18 21:35 emu10k1.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3076 Jun 18 21:35 hdsp.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5464 Jun 18 21:35 hdspm.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4238 Jun 18 21:35 sb16_csp.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7430 Jun 18 21:35 sfnt_info.h

the folder has the drwxr-xr-x permissions and the files -rw-r--r-- and that is translated in chmod 777 or 644 .. or other permission....

so if you have modified with the chmod command is a jungle to make every file back as they was...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: Woow! Thanks for answering. There isn't a command I can run to restore everything to default?